# XPath query: How to find all the <div> that have 2 <a> as the first 2 elements?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

XPath query: How to find all the `<div>` that have 2 `<a>` as the first 2 elements?

For instance, to find all `<div>`, using `$xpath->query();` where:

```
<div>
<a href="https://www.somesite.com/" id="" src="" alt="" /></a>
<a href="https://www.somesite.com/" id="" style=""></a>

... more elements of various kinds ...

</div>

... more elements of various kinds ...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//div[*[1][self::a]][*[2][self::a]]
```

will select all `div` elements which have `a` elements in the first and second child positions.

So, for example, for this XML,

```
<div>
  <div id="d1"></div>
  <div id="d2"><a/></div>
  <div id="d3"><div/><a/><a/></div>
  <div id="d4"><a/><a/></div>
  <div id="d5"><a/><a/><a/></div>
</div>
```

only these `div` elements,

```
<div id="d4"><a/><a/></div>
<div id="d5"><a/><a/><a/></div>
```

will be selected, as requested.

Comment: Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to write it (more consuming though) :

```
//a[count(preceding-sibling::*)=1 and preceding-sibling::*[1][self::a]][parent::div]/..
```

Look for an `a` element child of a `div`, with 1 preceding-sibling which is an anchor. Then get the parent.